# Div tag center in browser window using margin 0px auto

Tags: html, css

I can not get this one div container to center within the browser page horizontally...

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="copyrightposition clearfix">
                <p class="copyright clearfix">copyright2013 Rachael 
    Stetson Design Inc.</p>
                <p class="copyright clearfix">|</p>
                <p class="copyright 
    clearfix">www.rachaelstetson.com</p>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.copyrightposition {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
.copyright {
position: relative;
float: left;
font-size: 65%;
padding-right: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.19em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

margin: 0 auto; only works for elements with set width and they cannot be floated.

Comment: do the elements have to be set as inline then so they will sit side by side?

Comment: margin: 0 auto; only works on block-level elements. I'm not sure what you are asking but I'm guessing what you want is for the copyrightposition to have a fixed width and not be floated and the paragraphs inside can be floated, it doesn't matter as far as using amrgin: 0 auto; for the div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nv3Xv/ here's a fiddle showing what you are probably looking for. if you uncomment the width/margin part, you'll see how the copyright behaves then. if you want the text itself to be centered, you need to use inline with text-align: center; as in the example. you could just use span instead of p in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFrYF/).

I used `text-align:center`.

HTML

```
<div class="copyrightposition clearfix">
  <p class="copyright clearfix">copyright &copy lorem ipsum |  www.rachaelstetson.com</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.copyrightposition {
  text-align: center;
}
.copyright {
  font-size: 65%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.19em;
}
```